# Flexslider last slide not showing <canvas>

Tags: canvas, flexslider

In each of my Flexslider slides, I have a canvas element that I populate with a chart from Chart.js, but for some reason the last slide doesn't show it.

If the 3d slide is the last, the 3d doesn't show it. If the 5th is the last, the 5th doesn't who it.

HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <canvas id="pie0" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
        <h1>1st slide</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
        <canvas id="pie1" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
        <h1>2nd slide</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
        <canvas id="pie2" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
        <h1>3d and last slide</h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true,  
  });
});

var pieData = [
            {
                value: 72,
                color:"#EBB035"
            },
            {
                value : 28,
                color : "#eee"
            }

        ];

new Chart(document.getElementById("pie0").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(pieData);

new Chart(document.getElementById("pie1").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(pieData);

new Chart(document.getElementById("pie2").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(pieData);
```

See jsFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/bw24s/

Any thoughts? A bug? Thanks!